# How to get certificate from pkcs7 file

Tags: c++, cryptoapi, pkcs#7

I have a pkcs#7 file with included signers certificate, CA certificate, CRL. Now, to verify signature from this file I get the certificate from it. I try to do:

```
HANDLE hFile; 
if(!(hFile = CreateFile(L"c:\\users\\timur\\desktop\\sign_pkcs7.sig",
                            GENERIC_READ,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            NULL)))
{
    printf("Error opening file %d\n", GetLastError());
}

HCERTSTORE hPkcsStore = 0;
if(!(hPkcsStore = CertOpenStore(
                    CERT_STORE_PROV_PKCS7,
                    MY_TYPE,
                    NULL,
                    CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG,
                    hFile)))
{
    printf("Cert not found in pkcs7 store error %d.\n",GetLastError());
}
```

But while calling CertOpenStore program fails with **Access violation reading location 0x0000001c.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CryptQueryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open the P7B file or files in many other formats (the code will be the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7282440/315935)).

Comment: Thank You! I'll try it. Now I use functions such as CryptMsgUpdate, CryptMsgGetParam etc..